# Name for this matrix product condition

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology

Let $n\ge m,$ let $A$ be an $m\times n$ matrix and $B,$ an $n\times m$ matrix. 
Suppose the matrices satisfy
$$AB=I_m\tag 1$$

If $n=m$ this simply means $B=A^{-1}.$ Is there a name for this condition when $n>m?$

If not, is there a geometric interpretation?

Comment: You could call it a pseudoinverse. Also works if any of A or B is not full rank but they are $n=m$.

Comment: I would say that $A$ is a left inverse for $B$ and $B$ is a right inverse for $A$.  This implies that the map $x \mapsto Bx$ is one-to-one and the map $x \mapsto Ax$ is onto.